# jquery trigger click event one at a time

Tags: jquery, wordpress, triggers

I have an a simple quiz app which I'd like to add a functionality to automatically bring the next question.

As of now after people select an answer they have to click 'Next' to see the next question. I'd like to trigger a click event on the `Next` button when an answer is selected.

Keep in mind all the questions are loaded and are hard coded into the html but styled to display:none; so when we're clicking next essentially what is happening is we're setting the next one to be visible and the current one invisible.

Here's what I've tried with half solution.

The problem with my code is that it triggers click on the last `next` button when it should 
do it to the button in the same parent.

```
$ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.wpProQuiz_questionListItem").click(function() {

        $(this).parent("li").closest('.next').trigger('click');     
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

Here's my code structure.

```
<ol>
<li>
 <div>
  <ul>
   <h2>q1</h2>
    <li>answer 1</li>
    <li>answer 2</li>
    <li>answer 3</li>
     <button class="next">
   </ul>
  </div></ul>
<li style="display:none;">
 <div>
  <ul>
   <h2>q2</h2>
    <li>answer 1</li>
    <li>answer 2</li>
    <li>answer 3</li>
     <button class="next">
   </ul>
  </div></li>
<li style="display:none;">
     <div>
      <ul>
       <h2>q3</h2>
        <li>answer 1</li>
        <li>answer 2</li>
        <li>answer 3</li>
         <button class="next">
       </ul>
      </div></li>
    </ol>
```

Thank you.
Ps it may seem solved when

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you're trying to pass in the "click" event, just on document ready check for any element been checked and the .fadeIn() the next li child.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked')) {
    $('li:first-child').next().fadeIn('slow');
}});
```

Comment: Great suggestion. I'm much closer to getting it right.